# What is the matrix representing a positive operator called?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, hermitian-matrices

Considering finite dimensional spaces: Positive operators are a subset of hermitian operators. They have a matrix representation. Therefore one often uses both terms (the operator and the matrix representation) interchangably (e.g. in Quantum Mechanics). Is said matrix called "positive" (just like the operator) or "positive semidefinite" (which would be usual when only considering matrices)?

The definition of positive operators I use: A hermitian operator $A$ is called positive, if for any vector $|\psi\rangle$, the scalar product $(|\psi\rangle,A|\psi\rangle)$ is a real,non-negative number.

Comment: Positive operators are a proper subset of Hermitian operators. For example $-1$ is Hermitian in one dimensional spaces but is not positive. You shouldn't use them interchangeably.  They also don't have to have a matrix representation in infinite dimensional spaces which is why the notion of a positive operator doesn't appeal to matrices. It also helps us avoid choosing a basis which can lead to complications.

Comment: They're called positive semidefinite matrices. Matrix representations of strictly positive operators are called positive definite matrices. The term “positive matrix” means entrywise positive matrices. Similarly, “nonnegative matrix” refers to an entrywise nonnegative matrix.